# How to update a template_string on app creation?

Tags: python, templates, flask

Say we use Flask-User to show basic login\logout\edit user page\main page content. Yet their [base.html](https://github.com/lingthio/Flask-User-starter-app/blob/1c892d57dc1aff550d171c017031a45b2905d66b/app/templates/layout.html#L27) is not perfect (static app name for example embeded into base.html). Say we can only have one python script file for our application (dependencies- yes, additional `.html` template files-no). How to edit a Flask template_string  (for base.html) directly from python code?

Comment: This question is very unclear. Normally you pass all the information to render a template from the Flask code, so you should explain why you can't do that.

Comment: @DanielRoseman: [Sometimes](https://github.com/lingthio/Flask-User-starter-app/blob/1c892d57dc1aff550d171c017031a45b2905d66b/app/templates/layout.html#L27) template code can (a) need to be edited (b) used by all other templates. I want to be able to edit that base template from code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility is to create a custom `FileSystemLoader` class and modify the appropriate template contents returned from its `get_source` method.

A simple example:

**base.html** This is the template we want to modify. Suppose we don't like the contents of the `title` tag.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title set in base template</title>
</head>
<body>

{% block content %}
{% endblock content %}

</body>
</html>
```

**index.html** This is our template that extends `base.html`.

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    <h1>Home Page</h1>
{% endblock content %}
```

**app.py** Our simple Flask app.

```
import os
from flask import Flask, render_template
from jinja2 import FileSystemLoader


class CustomFileSystemLoader(FileSystemLoader):

    def __init__(self, searchpath, encoding='utf-8', followlinks=False):
        super(CustomFileSystemLoader, self).__init__(searchpath, encoding, followlinks)

    def get_source(self, environment, template):
        # call the base get_source
        contents, filename, uptodate = super(CustomFileSystemLoader, self).get_source(environment, template)

        if template == 'base.html':
            print contents
            # Modify contents here - it's a unicode string
            contents = contents.replace(u'Title set in base template', u'My new title')

            print contents

        return contents, filename, uptodate


app = Flask(__name__)

app.jinja_loader = CustomFileSystemLoader(os.path.join(app.root_path, app.template_folder))


@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('index.html')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Run the app and notice the title change in the browser.